# sqlalchemy upsert between tables with relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**Question?**

What is the most elegant way to insert if new and update if it exists between tables with a relationship in the same postgres DB using sqlalchemy?

**Context**
Users review a stage table; can accept changes that then get sent to the production table after review.

The stage table may have new records or just edited records compared to the production table.

I figured out how to do this from in peices from other questions, but all of them involve making a new object and specifying the column names e.g.

```
 rutable.ru=rustage.ru
 ...ect....
```

**My model**

```
class rutable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ru    =db.Column(db.String(6), db.ForeignKey('rustage.ru'),unique=True)      

class rustage(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ru    =db.Column(db.String(6), index=True, unique=True)
    rutablelink = db.relationship('rutable', lazy='dynamic', backref='ruback')
```

**Pseudo code**

```
#check to see if records exists
if db.session.query(exists().where(models.rutable.id == rurow)).scalar():
    rustage=models.rustage.query.filter_by(id=rurow).first()
    ruprod=models.rutable.query.filter_by(id=rurow).first()
    form = rutable(obj=rustage)
    # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    form.populate_obj(ruprod)
else:
    rustage=models.rustage.query.filter_by(id=rurow).first()
    #how do i insert rustage into rutable and reset primary key?
    #without creating a new obj in which i have to specify each column name?
    #e.g. rutable(a=rustage.a,.....  1 million column names (i could use a form?

db.session.commit()
```

**UPDATE**

i decided to go with a form
here is what i came up with

```
rustage=models.rustage.query.filter_by(id=rurow).first()
if db.session.query(exists().where(models.rutable.id == rurow)).scalar():
    ruprod=models.rutable.query.filter_by(id=rurow).first()
    form = rutable(obj=rustage)
    form.populate_obj(ruprod)
else:
    ruprod=rutable(ru=rustage.ru)
    form = rutable(obj=rustage)
    form.populate_obj(ruprod)
rustage.reviewEdit=False
ruprod.reviewEdit=False
db.session.commit()
```